# Different value for same property

Tags: qt, qml

'''

```
Item {
 Rectangle {

 height: 100;
 width: 100;
 color: "red"
 anchors.right: someOtherRectId.left;
 anchors.rightMargin: someOtherRectId.x > 200 ? 100: 0;

 Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("Other Rectangle X co-ordinate: ", someOtherRectId.x)
  } 
 }
 Rectangle {
  id: someOtherRectId
  height: 100;
  width: 100
  color: "gold"
  anchors.centerIn: parent
  }
}
```

In the above code even though someOtherRectId.x is greater than 200(ex 300) anchors.rightMargin is getting the value 0. I also checked using log statements as well.
Why this kind of behavior is observed?

Comment: please provide [mcve], at least the another rectangle

Comment: Maybe your problem is you have a typo. `anchors.centreIn` should be `anchors.centerIn`.

Comment: I ran your code and it gives someOtherRectId.x as -50. The root item does not have a width/height specified so centering it gives a negative x-value. Are you sure there's nothing missing from your code?

Comment: As it was company code I made some changes and uploaded the above code. The code doesn't miss anything as I have replicated it.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use two positioner systems in the same component and you cannot do this.

There are fourth ways to position items:

- Manual Positioning: with x and y.
- Anchors: with anchor.left, anchor.centerIn ...
- Layout: with RowLayout, ColumnLayout ...
- Positioner with Row, Column, Flow ...

For a solution, use this code:

```
    Item {
    Rectangle {
        height: 100
        width: 100
        color: "red"
        anchors.right: someOtherRectId.left
        anchors.rightMargin: someOtherRectId.x > 200 ? 100: 0

        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("Other Rectangle X co-ordinate: ", someOtherRectId.x)
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: someOtherRectId
        
        x: parent.x + (width / 2)
        y: parent.y + (height / 2)
        height: 100
        width: 100
        color: "gold"
    }
}
```

For more details on the positioning system

- See the doc: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-usecase-layouts.html
- This video: https://youtu.be/vzgTo14ljcY

Comment: Thank you for the reply :). Both the rectangles are drawn on window. But my question is that the expression in anchors.rightMargin is always evaluating to false even though when it should be true. I used console to check someOtherRectId.x value as well.

Comment: This is incorrect. Mixing ways to position items is fine, unless you do it non-sensically.
Mixing height/width and anchors.right is OK. Same for height/width and anchors.centerIn. But setting x will be overwritten by anchors.right, that's not the case in OP's post though. For positionners, you can have anchors.top in an item managed by a Row, but not anchors.right for example.